# Half-screen TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, viewflipper

how can I display a Tabhost in the bottom half of the screen, displaying a static picture (can under no circumstances be reloaded/redisplayed each time you swipe).

```
+--------------------------+---+---+
| =                        | * | ? |   < Action Bar with Help, Settings and 
+--------------------------+---+---+     a sliding drawer from the left
|                                  |     should be present.
|                                  |
|                                  |
|              static              |   < This should, regardless of the tab 
|           picture/map            |   < selected, be the same.
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
| TAB1 | TAB2 | TAB3 | TAB4 | TAB5 |   < There will be about 20 Tabs, if
+----------------------------------+     that is of any relevance
|                                  |
|     TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT     |   < Only the Text should, depending on 
|     TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT     |   < the selected Tab, be switched
|     TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT     |   < accordingly.
|     TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT     |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

If this is not possible, what can I use? I've head of TextSwitcher, but that doesn't really have the nice continous swipe animation of the tabHost.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have two vertically positioned `Fragment`s in your `Activity` as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.whatever.ImageFragment"
          android:id="@+id/image_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.whatever.TabHostFragment"
          android:id="@+id/tabhost_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The top `Fragment` would hold the `MapView` or `ImageView`, and the bottom fragment would contain the `FragmentTabHost` with the text `Fragment`s. Note that in this case the `FragmentTabHost` would be forced to use the `getChildFragmentManager()` method to get the text `Fragment`s.